# How to set value for Dynamically created TexBox in winforms

Tags: .net, winforms, textbox

I am trying to set value to Dynamically created TextBox in Winforms.But it doesnot Working.

Comment: Provide some code. Did you try it with textbox.Text ?

Comment: Yes i tried.Dynamically created text box not getting data and I can set text for statically placed text box.Please help me to sort out the issue.

Comment: If you don't provide some code, we can't help you..